# Duvida simples de C# no Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu não sei nada de C#, porém estou tentando desenvolver um simples projeto no Unity. Consiste na movimentação de uma ponte rolante. Eu fiz o código pra movimenta a ponte, porém, se eu continuo segurando o botão ele continua movimentando além do limite.

Como posso limitar o movimento entre dois pontos, neste caso, do eixo X já que ele só se movimenta nele.

Aqui está o código:

```
public class MoveBarra : MonoBehaviour {
    public float VelocidadeMov;

    void Start () {
        VelocidadeMov = .25f;
    }

    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.Translate(-VelocidadeMov, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.Translate(VelocidadeMov, 0, 0);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: E quais são esses dois pontos? São arbitrários, são até o final da visão câmera, ou outra coisa?

Comment: São dois pontos que eu quero arbitrar. Como visto no código ele só se move pelo eixo X e, eu quero que ele vá no máximo até -5 do eixo X até 6 do eixo X.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Mathf.Clamp` para restringir a movimentação o objeto.

```
transform.position = new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, -5f, 6f),transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```